# How to hide primary key, because I need them in the URL

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I'm creating a new Laravel application and my typical way of forming the urls is this:

```
/something.{post} //Ex: www.domain.com/something.123
```

Since Laravel offers route model binding, I can use the `123` to quickly identify the relevant model in the database.

My new project does not need me to have incrementing id column. I'm therefore considering going with UUID OR simple 5-character long random alpha-num string.

However, even with this new approach, I'll end up exposing my primary key ids in the URL. Can someone help me figure out a way to address this problem?

I read that Medium makes use of hashed IDs in their URLs. The only way I can think of solving this problem is having a separate table that maps my unique string with integer IDs; so that I can have urls like -

```
/something.ds92s
```

Which will internally map to say id `10` of my model.

Is this the right way?

Comment: First, `.{post}` seems like a bad idea. What if the value of `{post}` is `com`? Now you have a `.com` in the middle of your URL (not sure if an actual issue or not, but would look weird). The typical approach is `/` or `-`. Second, with proper security/routing, exposing the ID in the URL shouldn't be an issue. If the person is guessing at the ID, have other logic (like authentication, record association, etc.) that prevents them from accessing what they shouldn't.

Comment: {post} would always be a number which corresponds to the ID of the model in my database. If someone enters anything bad; it simply throws 404. I"m guessing that I'm unnecessarily bothering about hiding my primary keys.

Comment: That's true, unless you configured it to slugs/UUIDs. And yeah, by default, it would 404, but all I mean is that a proper authentication model, and maybe roles/permissions would enhance the security of those URLs. I have the opinion that you're overthinking it, but in some cases it's a valid concern. If you think it's worth putting time and effort into obscuring them, then go for it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additionally you can use unique slugs. Medium actually uses slugs along with hashed ids appended at the end to achieve uniqueness. But, I dont think exposing uuid is a big security concern. Exposing normal incrementinng id is a concern because people can guess ids and keep on trying different ids to achieve whatever mishap they intend to achieve.